# How to remove "file is not writable" in PyCharm?

Tags: git, macos, ide, pycharm

**For me, an Open project has so many other projects (all git repositories).**

I have multiple git repositories in one Folder And I have open that Folder as Project. So one project has at least 10 subprojects (all git repositories).

My problem inside one repository (subproject), I can't able to edit some files. Pycharm gives popup error saying "File is not writable". I can not find a proper solution to this problem.

In my search I found

1) Checked "Show 'Clear read-only status' Dialog" in Preferences/Version Control/Confirmation

2) Opening Pycharm with root privillages. But that didn't work for me.

3) Run following commonds (I guess it for windows and appear to not work for me)

```
attrib -r +s C:\WorkingDir

attrib -r +s C:\WorkingDir\*

attrib -r c:\folder\*.* /s /d
```

4) Obviously the lock icon on the bottom. That is unclickable for me for Read-only Files.

The interesting fact is If I open the same subproject in a different window (not with other subprojects) that I can edit it. But It makes my life difficult because I have to go back and forth. I like to open all my project together. And also because PyCharm doesn't support the opening project on different Tabs.

***My PyCharm version is 2017.1.4 (Professional) And Mac Os version is 10.12.4***

How will I **make those files editable**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Mac, open terminal and write the following:

```
sudo chmod a+w /home/somefolder/file.py
```

enter your password and then check your editor. You will be able to edit the file then.

Comment: And if you're not using MAC, what can you do to solve the issue?